# Is there an fast algorithm computing powers multiple a one-half?

Tags: c++, performance, differential-equations, computation

I'm writing a program for solving of planar restricted three-body problem. Its equations are below. This function computes derivatives of position and velocity and write them to array.

```
valarray<double> force(double t, valarray<double> r)
{
    valarray<double> f(dim);
    valarray<double>r0(r-rb0);
    valarray<double>r1(r-rb1);      

    f[0]=   2 * r[1] + r[2] - (1 - mu)*r0[2]/norm3(r0) - mu*r1[2]/norm3(r1);
    f[1]= - 2 * r[0] + r[3] - mu*r0[3]/norm3(r0) - mu*r1[3]/norm3(r1);
    f[2] = r[0];
    f[3] = r[1];
    return f;
}

double norm3(valarray<double> x)
{
    return pow(x[2]*x[2]+x[3]*x[3],1.5);
}
```

So I have to compute square of position vector and then raise it to power of 3/2. I think that these operations take a big part of computation time.

Now I use pow function of math.h. Is there another faster algorithm for computation this power? I tried to use [fast inverse square root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) (and cube it later) but it gives too imprecise value for my purposes and works longer (perhaps because of cubing).

Thanks!

Comment: I think two particular implementations that are often used are 1. the exponential identity (`x^1.5 = exp(ln(x) * 1.5)`) and using [Taylor's polynomial.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem)

Comment: how did you "cube it later"? using `pow` or `x * x * x`?

Comment: Why can't you use  t=x[2]*x[2]+x[3]*x[3]; return t*sqrt(t)?

Comment: *"I think that these operations take a big part of computation time."* Don't think, check! Use a profiler to find the real culprits in your program.

Comment: another thing: pass the valarray by const reference, it doesn't need to be copied for the norm calculation

Comment: If you use GCC don't forget to test whether compiler optimizations take care of your problems (`-O2` or `-O3`). For example, without optimizations copy-constructing all `valarray`s takes about whooping 40% of the time.

Comment: Thank you all for advice! My program became for 5 times faster.

Comment: You should also check whether the compiler has optimized to only call `norm3(r0)` once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple approach might be try x*sqrt(x), but benchmark it to be sure.

```
double norm3(valarray<double> x)
{
    double result=x[2]*x[2]+x[3]*x[3];
    result=result * sqrt(result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `FSQRT` in a Family 15h AMD64 processor takes 52 cycles. The SSE2 variants take 29 for a scalar value and 38 for a packed operation. The C version of `sqrt()` is probably a few extra instructions, but I doubt it's that much more.

If you want relatively precise results, I doubt there is much better to be got from some other operation. Most likely, anything producing good precision involving `pow()`, `exp()` and `log()`, etc, will take longer.

However, asking on the internet does not beat your own benchmarks. If this is a critical part of your code, try some different variants, and see what you get.